# Add GPX dynamically with openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am trying to show different routes from gpx files by selecting them from checkboxes, but the vector layer doesn't appear.

I used as a guide the examples from OpenLayers webpage: [GPXDATA](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/gpx.html) and [DragandDrop](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop-image-vector.html) without results.

Main.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mapa simple de OpenStreetMap con Open Layers</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="maintitle">Rutas de Limpieza</h1>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>Mostrar Rutas</li>
                <ul>Rutas de Barredoras
                    <li><input id="r1" name="ba_r1" type="checkbox">Ruta B1</li>
                    <li><input name="ba_r2" type="checkbox">Ruta B2</li>
                    <li><input name="ba_r3" type="checkbox">Ruta B3</li>
                </ul>                    
            </ul>
            <button id="sr_btn">Mostrar Rutas Seleccionas</button>
        </div>


        <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
window.onload = function(){
var defaultStyle = {
    'Point': new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.5)'
        }),
        radius: 5,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#ff0',
          width: 1
        })
      })
    }),
    'LineString': new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#f00',
        width: 3
      })
    }),
    'Polygon': new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(0,255,255,0.5)'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#0ff',
        width: 1
      })
    }),
    'MultiPoint': new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255,0,255,0.5)'
        }),
        radius: 5,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#f0f',
          width: 1
        })
      })
    }),
    'MultiLineString': new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#00f',
        width: 3
      })
    }),
    'MultiPolygon': new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(25,120,255,0.5)'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#00f',
        width: 1
      })
    })
};

var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
    var featureStyleFunction = feature.getStyleFunction();
    if (featureStyleFunction) {
      return featureStyleFunction.call(feature, resolution);
    } else {
      return defaultStyle[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
    }
};

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([2.5, 39.5]),
      zoom: 12
    })
});

var btn_sr = this.document.getElementById("sr_btn").addEventListener('click', function(){        
    var vector1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          url: 'gpx/qq2.gpx',
          format: new ol.format.GPX()
        }),
        style: defaultStyle
    });

    map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Vector({
        renderMode: 'image',
        source: vector1,
        style: styleFunction
    }));
});
}
```

For what can I understand from API the map.addLayer function should put vector1 layer top on the layers collection and show automatically, but instead I have this error: "uncaught exception: AssertionError: Assertion failed. See https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/doc/errors/#41 for details." 
Which means : Expected an ol.style.Style or an array of ol.style.Style.

But var defaultStyle is already an array of Styles, so I don't understand the error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 places where you set styles in your code

- `style: defaultStyle`
- `style: styleFunction`

`styleFunction` is working correctly (it returns a style based on the geometry type).
On the contrary, `defaultStyle` is not working because it's not an "ol.style.Style or an array of ol.style.Style." but it's an object.

To fix the issue, you can

- replace `style: defaultStyle` with `style: styleFunction`.
- if your GPX contains only points, you can use `style: defaultStyle['Point']`
- if it contains only lines, you can use `style: defaultStyle['LineString']`